# CSS - IOS and Android fixed position element jumps when scroll reaches the end

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the following style:

```
.footer-buttons {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

It works fine on computers. In mobiles when it reaches the end of the scroll height an ugly jump happens.
I believe it's because of the address bar in mobile phones.

I just added the following event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => alert(window.outerHeight()));
```

and found out when I reach the end of the page three continuous window resizes happen.
Initial normal window outerHeight is 640.

First: outerHeight is same as initial 640, but for some reason the resize event is triggered.

[image]

Second: This is when the problem occurs:

[image]

Third: At the end it just backs to its normal position and alerts 640 again.

Comment: Try to replace `fixed` with `sticky`.

Comment: @Vadzim I want it to always be at the bottom. `sticky`  puts it at the end of the page and it's not always showing.